# Data driven tool for gamedesigner

Tags: game-design, xml, data-driven

I'm looking for a software my gamedesigner can use setting monster characteristics.

Like one row of all monster types (and ability to add new ones)
One column of all 'templates' (normal, small, big, healer... and new ones)
and in each cell between them (like in excel), say for the Zombie-Rat, there would be data to store, say HP, speed, images to use, etc.

I have tried to do this in an excel spread sheet and export in .csv / .xml **but I can only have one information per cell in excel** (actually .ods).

Would be nice if it is free too.

Tl;dr I need a tool that my non-programming gamedesigner can use to save data with and that I can get the data out from.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just continue using excel, but change the layout of the data to have multiple cells per definition?

Comment: [Articy: draft](http://www.nevigo.com/en/articydraft/overview/) is game design tool with several features and export options. It is paid, though.

Comment: Since this is essentially a "which tech to use" question, I've voted to close.

Comment: @Byte56 can you do that (in a generic way) in Open Office?

Comment: Forget it, I'll guess it isn't on the chart asking a question in a comment.

Comment: You're welcome to come to chat and talk about it. Presenting what you have already in more detail so we can help find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a simple tool that allows a game designer to create entities and allow them to configure all of the values you mentioned here and when they are done, have it save the Entity out to a custom file. This custom file can be laid out in whatever fashion you want and could be read in by the engine.

I am personally working on a game engine project where I have embedded the Squirrel scripting language and I have provided a simple C++-side API that can be accessed by the scripting language to create the UI. I also wrote a tool for designing levels. I was thinking about integrating this type of Entity configuration directly into my level editor so the designer can populate the level with entities.

As I said, these data files can be read in at run-time and if you design the API / tool well enough it should be easy for your designer to grasp.

Comment: I'm a programmer, I know how to build tools but I know even better to not do it when there are already tools out there that will do the job (and sometimes even whole communities making them better). Thanks anyway. Now, SO / GameDev seems to have closed its doors for this kind of questions (which, if they don't turn into flamewars are very useful I think), may it be that way. Bye.

Comment: @Valmond I realized after looking at your profile you were definitely a programmer. I figured my answer would be meaningless to you specifically but chose to leave it up in case someone had never thought about "rolling their own" especially if they do not need a complicated solution. But yes, looking for existing robust solutions is always a good idea first. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem Dean Knight, it is also nice for other people browsing the internet finding answers that might suit them :-) Cheers!